# Difference in bash 3 between pipe and here-string

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection, here-string

If I run:

```
IFS=':' cat <<< $(echo $PATH)
```

then the ":" are used for word splitting and the output contains spaces instead of ":", but if I run:

```
echo $PATH | IFS=':' cat
```

they are not.

My understanding of pipes `a | b` is that they connect fd 1 of `a` to fd 0 of `b`.  And my understanding of herestrings `a <<< string` is that they write the string directly to fd 0 of `a`.  In either case it seems like the same thing should be written to fd 0 of cat.

That suggests that there should be no difference between the two commands, but clearly there must be something I've misunderstood because this shows a diff:

```
diff <(echo $PATH | IFS=':' cat) <(IFS=':' cat <<< $(echo $PATH))
```

I am not trying to accomplish something and asking for some text I can cut and paste to do it.  I have described a situation that contradicts my understanding and have asked for an explanation as to what I have misunderstood.

Can someone explain why these two commands produce different output?

---

I just tried this on bash 4 and do not get a difference there.  That's why I asked "What version of Bash are you on"... So, I've edited the question to limit it to bash 3.  I am not asking about bash 4.

Again, the question is not "can someone please give me something I can cut and paste to do a thing without thinking about it".  The question is "what is the difference between these two things".

Comment: I cannot reproduce a difference, unless I put a semicolon between the `IFS` assignment and the subsequent `cat`, which you don't have.

Comment: Interesting.  What version of bash are you on?

Comment: I'm on mac (ie bash 3), so I suppose it's possible there could be a difference there, but are you sure there's no difference?  Maybe try `diff <(echo $PATH | IFS=':' cat) <(IFS=':' cat <<< $(echo $PATH))`.

Comment: There was a change around v. 4.4 in the treatment of unquoted here-strings, although I'm not sure if that's relevant here. See for example [bash 3 and bash 5 evaluate herestring whitespace differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63605431/bash-3-and-bash-5-evaluate-herestring-whitespace-differently)

Comment: `cat <<< $(echo $PATH)` is the same as `echo $PATH | cat` is the same as `echo $PATH`

Comment: @JimL., they're not the same

Comment: Are you *definitely* in Bash ? Bash runs each element of a pipeline in a separate subshell. IIRC, ksh runs the last element as its direct child, and each previous pipe element as the child of its successor. That may be affecting the inheritance of IFS through the child processes.

Comment: If you have comments about answers you're getting, I suggest it might be helpful to post those comments under the answers themselves, instead of as edits to your question.

Comment: I have found that sometimes people interpret those as attacks, which is not my intent.  So, I try to make it "impersonal" by trying to clarify the question.  Though, honestly, it's been years since I've had a good experience on any SE site, so I think this will likely be my last attempt.

Comment: @Allen, with the tone you're using on your post, it's likely others aren't also having a good experience of you. You might try posting without the passive-aggressive complaints about the answers you got, and instead focus on clarity and giving useful information related to your post.

Comment: @Allen, E.g. I'm not sure why you'd write "All the responses keep fixating on "fixing" something", when one answer doesn't use the word at all, and the other only mentions bugs that have been fixed in the software (by the Bash maintainer, not the post author). Since you're not directly saying what you see as a problem, it's impossible to address the matter. So all that edit does, is just bitching and whining. After you've asked for help from strangers online, for free.

Comment: @Allen, calling people who try to help you for free "morons" is whining, yes. I'm not sure which part of what I wrote you're referring to with that "keeps trying to find out what I see as a problem". I read your post, saw the question "Can someone explain why these two commands produce different output?" (it's an oddity of old versions of Bash) and also the title asking about the "Difference between pipe and here-string" (newline handling). I wrote an answer trying to answer those questions.

Comment: I did describe a difference between different versions of Bash that seemed to me to explain the difference between the two commands you asked about. Is there something that was unacceptable with the explanation? Or is it just too simplistic to say "it's a bug"? I understand you don't like re-explaining yourself, but honestly, I'm just curious right now. So, humor me?

Comment: I will continue for a bit (and keep my frustrations to myself).  I did not ask about the difference between different versions of bash.  I pointed to two things in bash (which turned out to be specific to bash 3) that seem to be the same, but can be demonstrated to be different.  That suggests that I've misunderstood something, and I asked if someone can explain that.

Comment: @Allen, hmm, ok. What I was thinking was that the misunderstanding you had might be due to Bash 3 just being wrong here. That is, the new value of `IFS` in `IFS=':' cat <<< $(echo $PATH)` shouldn't affect the word splitting behaviour, any more than it does in `IFS=':' echo $PATH`, and since you rightly expected the correct behaviour, there was a mismatch. (Well, that's the part I _thought_ was the main issue underlying your post anyway, the difference between that and the one with a pipe stemming from said misbehaviour of the shell.)

Comment: Now, you're right that saying something about a misbehaviour/bug in Bash 3 doesn't in itself require comparing different versions, but the fact that the behaviour was changed to newer versions (and the fact that other shells have different behaviour) works as evidence about it _being_ a bug/misbehaviour in the first place. Which is why I brought the version difference up. Obviously, I thought it was clear from the context, but then again, communication is hard, so there's that.

Comment: Yes, of course I also mentioned quoting the variable expansions too, and perhaps you do know about all that already, but (frustratingly!) a lot of posts on the site make it clear that many people _don't_ (and answers might be read by people other than the one posting the question), so active users tend to get the habit of repeating it at every chance. Perhaps having it eventually become common knowledge is a vain hope, but on that part, I suppose you'll just have to excuse us in the meanwhile...

Comment: @Allen you are **always** going to have to think about the code you copy from places on the Internet when you try to use it in your scripts.  Advice on the Internet spans years (even decades) and usually doesn't take into account that the program has enjoyed bug fixes.  You may be able to blindly copy+paste 99 times out of 100, but there will be that remaining time that it doesn't work for you the way the Internet site caused you to believe it would work.  (the real ratio is more like 90% of the time copy works and 10% it doesn't)

Comment: @ilkkachu So, you're saying that the io/fd behavior I described is correct and the observed behavior is not due to something misunderstood? (that's actually a little disappointing; I'd thought I was going to learn something new). I know you mentioned it was a bug in your answer already, but if you could incorporate your comments above into your answer, I will mark it as accepted (mostly so future readers don't have to wade through the rest of the non-relevant discussion).

Comment: @Allen, edited a bit

Answer (score 2):

If you're seeing some odd behaviour in an old version of some software, there's a good chance it's due to a bug/misfeature that has since been fixed. It's often a good idea to use reasonably recent software versions.

The new value of `IFS` in

```
IFS=':' cat <<< $(echo $PATH)
```

shouldn't affect the word splitting behaviour, any more than it does in `IFS=':' echo $PATH`. Or, similarly, the new value of `var` shouldn't be used in `var=xyz cat <<< "$var"` any more than it is in `var=xyz echo "$var"`.

But exactly that happens with here-strings in Bash versions up to 4.0, while not in any other shell I tested. The fact that it's not in line with how other expansions work, and that other shells I tried don't have that behaviour hints at it being a bug. It's also changed to Bash 4.1 so apparently the Bash maintainer also thought it shouldn't do that.

The CHANGES file contains this change to `bash-4.1-alpha`, which only explicitly mentions here-docs, not here-strings, but otherwise sounds like it might be relevant:

```
jj. Fixed a bug that caused variable expansion in here documents to look in
    any temporary environment.
```

The misbehaviour there explains the difference between the command with the here-string and the one with the pipe.

---

As a somewhat related issue, the fact that the here string goes through word splitting to begin with is also a bug. There's no way to pass multiple distinct strings through a here-string, any more than it's possible to assign multiple strings through a regular assignment, so splitting makes as little sense on `cmd <<< $var` as it would in `foo=$var`. That one is fixed in Bash 4.4-beta:

```
z.  Bash no longer splits the expansion of here-strings, as the documentation
    has always said.
```

---

In any case, these two commands:

```
echo $foo | somecmd 
somecmd <<< $(echo $foo)
```

are not exactly the same, even with the two bugs fixed. Command substitutions remove any trailing newlines, and the here-string adds exactly one, while the pipeline does not modify the data passed through it.

The underlying mechanics are also vastly different, since in `cmd2 <<< $(cmd1)`, the shell likely needs to read in the whole output of `cmd1` before launching `cmd2`, while in `cmd1 | cmd2`, the two run in parallel and the shell doesn't need to touch the data.

Also, as always, if you want to use the unmodified value of a variable anywhere, you should double-quote the expansion.

Answer (score 1):

The `IFS=':' cat` can not possibly have an effect. You're introducing `IFS` as an environment variable to `cat`. That assignment is only visible to the `cat` process. `cat` doesn't do anything with `IFS`.

This version of the first example reproduces the splitting behavior for me:

```
(IFS=':'; cat <<< $(echo $PATH))
```

I put parentheses around it to execute it in a child shell, so that the assignment to `IFS` is scoped to that. It works because the `IFS` value is in effect when the result of the `$(echo ...)` command substitution is subject to expansions.

This behavior is **apparently* at odds with the documentation. The Bash man page says that `<<<word` does not perform word splitting. But that's what splitting using `IFS` is: it is word splitting.

What is in fact happening is **the substition of `$PATH` into the `echo` command is what is doing the `IFS`-based word splitting**.

Before the `cat <<< $(echo $PATH)` command is executed, `$PATH` is first expanded, and that's where `IFS` comes into play. The `echo` therefore produces the path split on spaces. That entire output becomes the `word` argument to `<<< word`, and is no longer subject to splitting.

Consider the behavior in each of these experiments:

```
# <<< prevents word splitting

$ (IFS=':'; abc='a:b:c'; cat <<<$abc )  # <<< prevents word splitting
a:b:c

# quotes prevent word splitting

$ (IFS=':'; abc='a:b:c'; cat <<<$(echo "$abc"))
a:b:c

# lack of quotes allows word splitting (same as $PATH example)

$ (IFS=':'; abc='a:b:c'; cat <<<$(echo $abc))
a b c

# Proof that a:b:c is already split coming from echo

$ (IFS=':'; abc='a:b:c'; cat <<<$(echo $abc | tr ' ' -))
a-b-c
```

Comment: It is likely that the word-splitting applies to the arguments of `echo`.  The given command could be reduced to `(IFS=':'; echo $PATH)` and it still works, i.e. without any `<<<`.

Comment: @JimL. No, what is happening is the interpolation of `$PATH` into the `echo` is doing it.

Comment: re: "The IFS=':' cat can not possibly have an effect", why does this show a diff? `diff <(cat <<< $(echo $PATH)) <(IFS=':' cat <<< $(echo $PATH))`

Comment: @Allen it doesn't, not on my machine anyway, and I cannot imagine why it would. Can you reproduce this in a new, clean shell session?

Comment: @Allen Did you assign a value to `IFS` and forget to restore it?

Comment: So, for the second time: "Interesting.  What version of bash are you on?"

Comment: @Allen, the question isn't what version Kaz and terdon are on, it's what version _you_ are on. Consider that you started the subject with your post about the odd behaviour you observed -- you could have helped everyone by immediately telling the details of your environment, including the version of the software you're using. The mention of a rather old version could have worked as a hint for the readers, and might have been helpful for you getting answers explaining the behaviour.

Comment: I didn't realize that it was version-related until he mentioned that he wasn't getting the same results.  He could've helped everyone by responding to my early question "What version of bash are you on?"